# Java Implementing copy completely from superclass when classes do not differ by data

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, copy, subclass

I have several subclasses of a class "A", say B, C, and D. I store several of these in a generic

```
ArrayList<A> stuff;
```

B, C, and D have absolutely no different data members than A. The only way they differ is by different overridden methods. I would LIKE to be able to copy any instance of class A to another instance of class A (while retaining the true subclass)

Something like:

```
A obj1 = (A)new B(...)
A obj2 = (A)new C(...)
A obj3 = obj1.copy();
// (obj3 instanceof B) == true
```

Normally this would require B, C, and D to implement custom copy methods. However, this seems like a waste since the data members are exactly the same, and they would only exist so that the class is preserved.

Is there any way I could get away with only implementing copy in class A, and still preserving the underlying classes of the objects?

EDIT:

If I'm thinking correctly, the problem I would run into if just the superclass had a copy method:

```
class A {
    int dataMember;
    public A copy() {
        A ret = new A(); // !!
        ret.dataMember = dataMember;
        return ret;
    }
```

}

When calling "new" I couldn't generically determine what subclass of A the class is, and furthermore explicitly instantiate an instance of that. Or is there  a way to do this?

Comment: Why not just give the super class a copy method?

Answer (score 1):

You could give `A` a [copy constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12):

```
class A {

    public A(A other) {
        //copy other's fields to this instance
    }
}
```

Subclasses of `A` could also expose a constructor that took an `A` instance and passed it to the `super` constructor:

```
class B extends A {

    public B(A other) {
        super(other);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [clone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29)? It will copy all your fields and mantain the derived class. Be careful that it won't do a clone of each field's object, but they will point to the same reference.

```
public Object clone() {
    try {
        return super.clone(); 
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {} // Will never happen if your object implements the Cloneable interface
}
```